# Что ставить после слов "на будущее"?

Tags: пунктуация

На будущее делай это после фильма, а не во время просмотра.

Answer (score 1):

По смыслу здесь сокращение от выражения "на будущее дам тебе такой (настоятельный) совет:", поэтому напрашивается двоеточие.

Без знаков препинания предложение выглядит как совет "делать что-то на будущее" - трудно представить себе дополнительный контекст, в котором такое выражение обрело бы естественный смысл.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно в таких случаях употребляют слова "впредь" и "в будущем". А слова "на будущее" в данном предложении "вводят" предупреждение или совет (который автор дает *на будущее*), поэтому после них должно идти двоеточие или тире.

Comment: Двоеточие или тире  как обязательный знак необоснованно  усложняют и письменный и устный вариант речи, обстоятельственное наречие вполне способно передать нужный смысл. Оно  может быть самостоятельным, то есть относиться ко всему предложению, а не к конкретному слову. Поэтому выбор здесь авторский: есть желание подчеркнуть и сделать паузу, то можно поставить тире (двоеточие).

Answer (score 0):

В сложных предложениях типа

> *На будущее вас предупреждаем: поаккуратнее*; *На  будущее помните: начальство должно знать всё*,

деление на части необходимо. Ваша фраза этого не требует, и пример из НКРЯ это подтверждает:

> *Но на будущее мы внимательно присматриваемся и к тому, как  городская администрация...*

Answer (score 0):

Можно точку - очень категорично и даже угрожающе.

Предлагаемое [редакторским бюро](http://popravilam.com/blog/080-znakomtes-vnimanie-kakoj-znak-stavit.html) тире мне не очень по вкусу, а это ведь вкусовая постановка знака (который нужен).

С упомянутым бюро мы сошлись на двоеточии.

*На будущее: делай это после фильма, а не во время просмотра.*

**[«Знакомьтесь», «Встречайте», «Разрешите представиться», «Внимание» и «Осторожно»: какой знак ставить после?](http://popravilam.com/blog/080-znakomtes-vnimanie-kakoj-znak-stavit.html)**

> ...***двоеточие или тире***? Возможен любой из этих знаков. Они ставятся между частями сложного бессоюзного предложения, а рассматриваемые примеры именно такие.
> Мы предпочитаем двоеточие: есть в нем что-то предупреждающее. Но выбор за пишущим.
>
> *Знакомьтесь: тетя Маша. / Знакомьтесь — тетя Маша*.
>
> *Встречайте: новый сотрудник. / Встречайте — новый сотрудник.*
>
> *Разрешите представиться: Иван, сослуживец вашего сына. / Разрешите представиться — Иван, сослуживец вашего сына.*
>
> Примеры из справочника Розенталя:
>
> *Знакомьтесь: Балуев. Внимание — ребёнок.*
>
> Добавим от себя фразы с «осторожно» — тот же принцип.
>
> *Внимание: дети! Внимание — обрыв!*
>
> *Осторожно: окрашено. Осторожно — скользко!*

Розенталя с вариациями можно почитать **[здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189)**.

Answer (score 0):

**На будущее** (= в будущем) делай это после фильма, а не во время просмотра.

Я думаю, что в этом случае не нужны знаки препинания.

Сравнить: **Но на будущее учти:** делай это после фильма, а не во время просмотра.

**БУДУЩЕЕ,** ср. 1. Период времени, который последует за настоящим; предстоящие события;  **Учти на б.** (совет, предупреждение не повторять ошибок, проступков).  2. Дальнейшая судьба, участь, карьера. **<В будущем,** в зн. нареч. Впоследствии, потом. **В будущем** увидим!

**Примеры:**

(1) Сегодня она, так и быть, примет устную информацию, но **на будущее** он должен сам все зашифровывать. [Вадим Кожевников. Щит и меч. Книга первая (1968)]

― Я не обвиняю вас, так как сама поступала так же, но **на будущее** этот ужасный факт с Володей должен показать вам, как чутко и бережно нужно относиться к людям. [В. В. Полонская. Последний год (1938)]

(2) Может, еще вернется, а скорей всего, к партизанам уйдет… А ты о нем забудь **и на будущее учти:** о закордонниках спрашивать не следует. [Владимир Богомолов. Иван (1957)]

Comment: Не уверен, что примеры из того же ряда, что и обсуждаемое предложение. В вопросе можно вместо "на будущее" поставить "в будущем", а вот в этом примере  нельзя: "На будущее этот ужасный факт с Володей должен показать вам...". А в этом примере спорно: "на будущее он должен сам все зашифровывать". И еще: даже если имеется в виду "в будущем", есть разница между прямым назиданием "делай это" и отстраненным "он должен". Перед назиданием двоеточие так и просится, просто кричит: "Поставьте меня".

Comment: Можно считать "на будущее" обстоятельственным детерминантом. Как известно, детерминант  на является присловным распространителем, а относится к основе предложения.  На будущее - это "на будущее время", если возникнет такая ситуация. Откуда здесь В.п. с предлогом НА?  Но ведь такая падежная форма может иметь значение времени, например: На будущее лето поедем отдыхать к морю. Это тоже детерминант, мы же не будем задавать вопрос  "поедем на что",